# Image not showing on phone but shows on Emulator

Tags: flutter, dart, gallery

In my Flutter application, ([Github link here](https://github.com/maylortaylor/ShowPhotoLock)) I am getting some inconsistent behavior. When I run the app in the emulator, I can choose an image from the image gallery (using **image_picker** package) and then display the image I picked on the screen.

However, when i build the app and and install the .apk file onto my phone, the the image just shows as blank white after I choose it from my gallery.

The "dora the explorer gif" is suppose to be behind the image.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:ShowPhotoLock/core/constants/app_strings.dart';
import 'package:ShowPhotoLock/core/viewmodels/views/baseWidget.dart';
import 'package:ShowPhotoLock/core/viewmodels/views/drawer/drawerOnly.dart';
import 'package:ShowPhotoLock/core/viewmodels/views/home/homeScreenViewModel.dart';
import 'package:ShowPhotoLock/core/viewmodels/widgets/photoViewWrapper.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  Future<File> _imageFile;

  pickImageFromGallery(ImageSource source) {
    setState(() {
      _imageFile = ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source);
    });
  }

  Widget showImage() {
    return FutureBuilder<File>(
      future: _imageFile,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<File> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
            snapshot.data != null) {
              return Center(child: Image.file(snapshot.data, width: 300, height: 300));
        } else if (snapshot.error != null) {
          return const Text(
            'Error Picking Image',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          );
        }
        return Center(
           child: Text( 'No Image',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1)
          );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BaseWidget<HomeScreenViewModel>(
      model: HomeScreenViewModel(sharedPreferencesService: Provider.of(context)), 
      builder: (context, model, child) => Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'Show Photo Lock',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,
        ),
      ),
      drawer: _imageFile == null ? DrawerOnly() : null,
      body:  _imageFile == null ? Container() : showImage(),
      floatingActionButton: _imageFile == null
          ? FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                pickImageFromGallery(ImageSource.gallery);
              },
              tooltip: 'Pick Image',
              child: Icon(Icons.photo_library),
              backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            )
          : Container(),
    ));
  }
}
```

**App working as expected on emulator:**
[image]

**App NOT working as expected on actual phone:**
[image]

Comment: Im new to flutter but maybe it has something to do with permissions like camera permissions also see this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29422

Comment: I tried adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />` and the `permission_handler` package. Both of these possible solutions did not solve the problem. Using the `permission_handler` package gave me lots of errors revolving around AndroidX compatibility issues.